# Point counting under polygon

Tags: gis

Getting count of points within a polygon. I have thousands of postal codes with buffers surrounding them and am required to get a count of intersections that fall beneath them. I am finding this difficult, I know that a spatial join would connect them but to get a count I am unsure. Would anyone one know how to conduct such an endeavor?

Comment: Can you specifiy a bit more? What type of gis are you using, or do you use a database like postgis? If i understand your question correct, you only want to count all points inside a specific polygon?

Comment: I am trying to make a count of 3-ways, 4-ways & dead end intersections that fall underneath a buffered point. I have the road intersections split into their own feature classes. I am using ArcGIS 10.5 Advance.